# Jquery working in console but not in actual code for checkbox enable disable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created one checkbox on the click on which the date fields are enabled/disabled

this is my code for jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mychechbox").click(function(){
        $("#date_1").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
});
```

my html tags for same:

```
<input id="date_1" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('from');  ?>" name="from" class="form-control" type="date" placeholder=" From" disabled/>
<p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">
    From Date<br><br>Enable Date fiedls
    <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left" id="mychechbox" name="mychechbox">
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" >
    <input id="date_2" value="<?php  $to= $this->input->post('to');if($to){echo $to;}else{echo date('m/d/y'); }  ?>" name="to" class="form-control" type="date" placeholder=" To" disabled/>
    <p class="pull-left" style="font-size:10px;">End Date </p>
</div>
```

I am doing this in Codeigniter.

please suggest me some improvements if needed

Comment: I am unable to see any element with id `start_bottom` in your current given code.

Comment: hi sorry i forgot to edit.. the element id is date_1

Comment: This should be working fine. Are you  facing any issue or seeing any error?

Comment: I did not find any of the issue , it is working on my side,Please check your console , are you want to enable/disable both of the date field ?

Comment: Make sure you have included the js file and is loading into the page you want or you placed it correct place. Can you please share URL for further checks?

Comment: may be the case is same `id` repeated multiple time in your HTML

Comment: @ascsoftw I am not facing any issue but when I inspected my checkbox, one more element is being loaded automatocally:<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie thats why I tried changing the id of my checkbox.. but it didnt work either

Comment: @ankitsingh yess .. but initially I am trying to enable one element only

Comment: @badprogrammer  working fine for me:- https://jsfiddle.net/47ya605L/

Comment: @badprogrammer i think you need to check this 
 In a html page only one jquery should be loaded after check this if only one jquery is loading then check in all the html page any other tags havind date_1 as id

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery and start mixing HTML5 with a deprecated (not yet obsolete) framework like jQuery?

Example only HTML5 + Pure JS:
[Enable/Disable input fields](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lfp2byx/)

**and if you do wanna use jQuery**
Don't use click cause than it will not work when checking/unchecking the checkbox when u use your keyboard.

Use the **change** event instead and verify the current state of the checkbox so whether it was checked or not.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mychechbox").change(function() {
    $("#date_1").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  });
});
```

Also use **prop** instead of **attr** to add the disabled property on an input field. Also recommend to use **#mycheckbox** with a **k** instead of **#mychechbox** with an **h** just to make sure that other people don't mistake if they write correct English.

Comment: Thanks @bojoer I will definitely try this.. but I have already tried on change event

Comment: Why not just use plain JS with HTML5? https://jsfiddle.net/4Lfp2byx/

Comment: What do you mean by soon „obsolete“ jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

So finally after so many attempts I got the solution:
I was unaware that along with my checkbox icheck-helper class(which I had mentioned in one of the comments) is also being loaded automatically...
so I did this:

```
$('#mycheckbox').on('ifChanged', function(event) {
         if(this.checked) {
                         // alert("yes");
                         $("#date_1").removeAttr("disabled");
                         $("#date_2").removeAttr("disabled");
         }

         else {
                         // alert("no");
                         $("#date_1").attr("disabled","disabled");
                         $("#date_2").attr("disabled","disabled");
         }
    });
```

thank you everyone for the answers

Answer (score -1):

if Your need to enable and disable datepicker on the basis of checkbox is checked or not then, try below code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mychechbox").click(function(){ 
              $("#mychechbox").is(':checked') ? $('#mydate').datepicker('enable') : $('#mydate').datepicker('disable');
        });
     });
```

Comment: Code will work but it are not jQuery DatePicker input Fields but just plain HTML5 input Fields of type date.

Comment: Also why use .is(':checked') if you do use jQuery just use .checked and since it is no jQuery DatePicker you will not be able to enable or disable them or you initiate a new DatePicker while the initial was meant to be an HTML5 field of type date.

Comment: Simple solution all in plain Vanilla JS and HTML5: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lfp2byx/